# layout_below not working with CoordinatorLayout android

Tags: android

This is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivityProductList">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>


    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewProduct"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="25dip"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/setting_selector"
        android:divider="#FFCC00"
        android:dividerHeight="2px"
        android:background="@color/windowBackground"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cart"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:elevation="6dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to set all 3 elements vertically. But they are overlapping in current layout.

layout_below doesn't seems to work here.

How to fix the issue?

Comment: wrap them with a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout

Answer (score 2):

I have mentioned a snippet of layout, i guess this is something you want. check on [github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/test_layout_coordinator_layout.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> output

can't help you with `FloatingActionButton`, it supposed to float , lol :)

[image]